# i am getting wrong timestamp and my date formatter is right

Tags: java, timestamp

```
String RollStart_TIMESTAMP = RollStartDATE_TIME_STAMP+" "+rolStart_TIME_STAMP;

                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm");
                Date parsedDate = null;
                try {
                    parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(RollStart_TIMESTAMP);
                    long mili  = parsedDate.getTime();
                    Log.e("VX:","TIMESTAMP"+mili);

                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.e("VX:","TIMESTAMP"+parsedDate);
```

Comment: How to you get RollStartDATE_TIME_STAMP and rolStart_TIME_STAMP?

Comment: Try below library for this [Link](https://github.com/CommonUtils/android).

Comment: Your pattern seems wrong. `m` stands for "minute in hour" but you use it where month would usually be. Try `new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, You get a right time stamp.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd,yyyy HH:mm aaa");
timestamp = dateFormat.format(new Date()); // Find todays date
Log.e("Timestamp", timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes right there is wrong pattern  yyyy-MM-hh is helps me out .

```
            try {
                String RollStart_TIMESTAMP = RollStartDATE_TIME_STAMP+" "+rolStart_TIME_STAMP;
                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

                Date timestamp = null;
                timestamp = df.parse(RollStart_TIMESTAMP);
                long ROLL_START_DATE_TIME_VALUE = timestamp.getTime()/1000;
                Log.e("RX:","VALUE"+ROLL_START_DATE_TIME_VALUE);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
```